# Use LINQ to XML in VB.NET

Tags: xml-parsing

I have a question regarding LINQ to XML in VB.NET.

How can I read specific attributes of an XML document and show the result in a listbox?

The attributes I would like to have in the listbox:

- Krantyp
- Klasse
- Radius
- Traglast

This is how the xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <Krane>   <Hersteller>
    <Marke>Liebherr</Marke>
    <Modell>
      <Krantyp>LTM 1030-2.1</Krantyp>
      <Klasse>30</Klasse>
      <Rüstzustand>
        <Rüstdetail>
          <ID>LTM 1030-2.1-A</ID>
          <Color1>CornflowerBlue</Color1>
          <TextOben1>30 m</TextOben1>
          <TextUnten1>T</TextUnten1>
          <Color2>Transparent</Color2>
          <TextOben2></TextOben2>
          <TextUnten2></TextUnten2>
          <Color3>Transparent</Color3>
          <TextOben3></TextOben3>
          <TextUnten3></TextUnten3>
          <Color4>Transparent</Color4>
          <TextOben4></TextOben4>
          <TextUnten4></TextUnten4>
          <Color5>Transparent</Color5>
          <TextOben5></TextOben5>
          <TextUnten5></TextUnten5>
          <Color6>LightCoral</Color6>
          <TextOben6>2,3 t</TextOben6>
          <TextUnten6>B</TextUnten6>
          <Traglasten>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>3</Radius>
              <Traglast>30,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>4</Radius>
              <Traglast>24,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>5</Radius>
              <Traglast>19,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>6</Radius>
              <Traglast>14,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>7</Radius>
              <Traglast>11,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>8</Radius>
              <Traglast>9,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>9</Radius>
              <Traglast>7,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>10</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>12</Radius>
              <Traglast>4,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>14</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>16</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>18</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>20</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>22</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>24</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>26</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
          </Traglasten>
        </Rüstdetail>
      </Rüstzustand>
      <Rüstzustand>
        <Rüstdetail>
          <ID>LTM 1030-2.1-B</ID>
          <Color1>CornflowerBlue</Color1>
          <TextOben1>30 m</TextOben1>
          <TextUnten1>T</TextUnten1>
          <Color2>Transparent</Color2>
          <TextOben2></TextOben2>
          <TextUnten2></TextUnten2>
          <Color3>Transparent</Color3>
          <TextOben3></TextOben3>
          <TextUnten3></TextUnten3>
          <Color4>Transparent</Color4>
          <TextOben4></TextOben4>
          <TextUnten4></TextUnten4>
          <Color5>Transparent</Color5>
          <TextOben5></TextOben5>
          <TextUnten5></TextUnten5>
          <Color6>LightCoral</Color6>
          <TextOben6>5,5 t</TextOben6>
          <TextUnten6>B</TextUnten6>
          <Traglasten>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>3</Radius>
              <Traglast>30,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>4</Radius>
              <Traglast>24,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>5</Radius>
              <Traglast>20,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>6</Radius>
              <Traglast>17,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>7</Radius>
              <Traglast>14,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>8</Radius>
              <Traglast>11,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>9</Radius>
              <Traglast>9,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>10</Radius>
              <Traglast>8,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>12</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>14</Radius>
              <Traglast>4,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>16</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>18</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>20</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>22</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>24</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>26</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
          </Traglasten>
        </Rüstdetail>
      </Rüstzustand>
      <Rüstzustand>
        <Rüstdetail>
          <ID>LTM 1030-2.1-C</ID>
          <Color1>CornflowerBlue</Color1>
          <TextOben1>30 m</TextOben1>
          <TextUnten1>T</TextUnten1>
          <Color2>CornflowerBlue</Color2>
          <TextOben2>8,6 m</TextOben2>
          <TextUnten2>K</TextUnten2>
          <Color3>Transparent</Color3>
          <TextOben3></TextOben3>
          <TextUnten3></TextUnten3>
          <Color4>Transparent</Color4>
          <TextOben4></TextOben4>
          <TextUnten4></TextUnten4>
          <Color5>Transparent</Color5>
          <TextOben5></TextOben5>
          <TextUnten5></TextUnten5>
          <Color6>LightCoral</Color6>
          <TextOben6>2,3 t</TextOben6>
          <TextUnten6>B</TextUnten6>
          <Traglasten>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>3</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>4</Radius>
              <Traglast>5,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>5</Radius>
              <Traglast>5,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>6</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>7</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>8</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>9</Radius>
              <Traglast>5,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>10</Radius>
              <Traglast>5,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>12</Radius>
              <Traglast>4,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>14</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>16</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>18</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>20</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>22</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>24</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>26</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>28</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>30</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
          </Traglasten>
        </Rüstdetail>
      </Rüstzustand>
      <Rüstzustand>
        <Rüstdetail>
          <ID>LTM 1030-2.1-D</ID>
          <Color1>CornflowerBlue</Color1>
          <TextOben1>30 m</TextOben1>
          <TextUnten1>T</TextUnten1>
          <Color2>CornflowerBlue</Color2>
          <TextOben2>15,0 m</TextOben2>
          <TextUnten2>K</TextUnten2>
          <Color3>Transparent</Color3>
          <TextOben3></TextOben3>
          <TextUnten3></TextUnten3>
          <Color4>Transparent</Color4>
          <TextOben4></TextOben4>
          <TextUnten4></TextUnten4>
          <Color5>Transparent</Color5>
          <TextOben5></TextOben5>
          <TextUnten5></TextUnten5>
          <Color6>LightCoral</Color6>
          <TextOben6>2,3 t</TextOben6>
          <TextUnten6>B</TextUnten6>
          <Traglasten>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>4</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>5</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>6</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>7</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>8</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>9</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>10</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>12</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>14</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>16</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>18</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>20</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>22</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>24</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>26</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>28</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>30</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>32</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>34</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>36</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
          </Traglasten>
        </Rüstdetail>
      </Rüstzustand>
      <Rüstzustand>
        <Rüstdetail>
          <ID>LTM 1030-2.1-E</ID>
          <Color1>CornflowerBlue</Color1>
          <TextOben1>30 m</TextOben1>
          <TextUnten1>T</TextUnten1>
          <Color2>CornflowerBlue</Color2>
          <TextOben2>8,6 m</TextOben2>
          <TextUnten2>K</TextUnten2>
          <Color3>Transparent</Color3>
          <TextOben3></TextOben3>
          <TextUnten3></TextUnten3>
          <Color4>Transparent</Color4>
          <TextOben4></TextOben4>
          <TextUnten4></TextUnten4>
          <Color5>Transparent</Color5>
          <TextOben5></TextOben5>
          <TextUnten5></TextUnten5>
          <Color6>LightCoral</Color6>
          <TextOben6>5,5 t</TextOben6>
          <TextUnten6>B</TextUnten6>
          <Traglasten>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>3</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>4</Radius>
              <Traglast>5,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>5</Radius>
              <Traglast>5,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>6</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>7</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>8</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>9</Radius>
              <Traglast>5,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>10</Radius>
              <Traglast>5,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>12</Radius>
              <Traglast>5,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>14</Radius>
              <Traglast>4,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>16</Radius>
              <Traglast>4,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>18</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>20</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>22</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>24</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>26</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>28</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>30</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>32</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>34</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>36</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
          </Traglasten>
        </Rüstdetail>
      </Rüstzustand>
      <Rüstzustand>
        <Rüstdetail>
          <ID>LTM 1030-2.1-F</ID>
          <Color1>CornflowerBlue</Color1>
          <TextOben1>30 m</TextOben1>
          <TextUnten1>T</TextUnten1>
          <Color2>CornflowerBlue</Color2>
          <TextOben2>15,0 m</TextOben2>
          <TextUnten2>K</TextUnten2>
          <Color3>Transparent</Color3>
          <TextOben3></TextOben3>
          <TextUnten3></TextUnten3>
          <Color4>Transparent</Color4>
          <TextOben4></TextOben4>
          <TextUnten4></TextUnten4>
          <Color5>Transparent</Color5>
          <TextOben5></TextOben5>
          <TextUnten5></TextUnten5>
          <Color6>LightCoral</Color6>
          <TextOben6>5,5 t</TextOben6>
          <TextUnten6>B</TextUnten6>
          <Traglasten>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>4</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>5</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>6</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>7</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>8</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>9</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>10</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>12</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>14</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>16</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>18</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>20</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>22</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>24</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>26</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>28</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>30</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>32</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>34</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,0</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>36</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>38</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,6</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>40</Radius>
              <Traglast>0,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
          </Traglasten>
        </Rüstdetail>
      </Rüstzustand>
    </Modell>   </Hersteller>   <Hersteller>
    <Marke>Tadano Faun</Marke>
    <Modell>
      <Krantyp>ATF 50G-3</Krantyp>
      <Klasse>50</Klasse>
      <Rüstzustand>
        <Rüstdetail>
          <ID>ATF 50G-3-A</ID>
          <Color1>CornflowerBlue</Color1>
          <TextOben1>40 m</TextOben1>
          <TextUnten1>T</TextUnten1>
          <Color2>Transparent</Color2>
          <TextOben2></TextOben2>
          <TextUnten2></TextUnten2>
          <Color3>Transparent</Color3>
          <TextOben3></TextOben3>
          <TextUnten3></TextUnten3>
          <Color4>Transparent</Color4>
          <TextOben4></TextOben4>
          <TextUnten4></TextUnten4>
          <Color5>Transparent</Color5>
          <TextOben5></TextOben5>
          <TextUnten5></TextUnten5>
          <Color6>LightCoral</Color6>
          <TextOben6>4,9 t</TextOben6>
          <TextUnten6>B</TextUnten6>
          <Traglasten>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>3</Radius>
              <Traglast>45,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>4</Radius>
              <Traglast>38,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>5</Radius>
              <Traglast>30,3</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>6</Radius>
              <Traglast>24,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>7</Radius>
              <Traglast>18,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>8</Radius>
              <Traglast>15,2</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>9</Radius>
              <Traglast>12,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>10</Radius>
              <Traglast>10,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>12</Radius>
              <Traglast>7,9</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>14</Radius>
              <Traglast>6,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>16</Radius>
              <Traglast>4,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>18</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,8</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>20</Radius>
              <Traglast>3,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>22</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,5</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>24</Radius>
              <Traglast>2,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>26</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,7</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>28</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,4</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
            <Schritt>
              <Radius>30</Radius>
              <Traglast>1,1</Traglast>
            </Schritt>
          </Traglasten>
        </Rüstdetail>
      </Rüstzustand>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, your Xml seems not to be valid and could be much shorter...